# Capture and redirect errors in Julia

Tags: exception, io, stream, output, julia

I am using this Julia blog [Capture Output in Julia](http://www.juliabloggers.com/capturing-output-in-julia/) to redirect the errors. However, due to asynchronous nature `atexit` function is called before STDERR is populated and the program hang when trying to read from empty stream. Related problems have been discussed in some Julia forums but I couldn't make a complete sense out of it.

I have partially solved the problem by catching the exception and then writing the exception to STDERR but the trace gets lost in the process and I only get to know the exception and not it's origin.

Can someone please help me? Is there a better solution to it? - Thanks

I am using Julia v0.5 on Mac Os X El Capitan v10.11.4

Below is a sample code that I am trying to run

```
errorRead, errorWrite = redirect_stderr()

atexit(function()
  close(errorWrite)
  redirect_stderr(STDOUT)
  for err in eachline(errorRead)
     println(err)
  end

  close(errorRead)
end) 

try erroneousfunc()
catch err
  println(STDERR, err)
  exit(0)
end
```

Comment: Can you add a minimal example, as well as Julia version and platform? I used the linked code but couldn't reproduce.

Comment: I must admit that it was working before and something happened. May be a Pkg.update() was run in between. Also, after spending a lot of time on it, I have taken a different route and solved my problem by adding errors to a BufferedStream and later reading from that stream.